Reload page with no querystring if original querystring yielded no results from a database query
I've the following code for filename usa.php
$query = "SELECT * FROM usa WHERE deleted='0' AND filename<>''";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
$stmt->execute(array());

$stmtcounterview = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usa WHERE deleted='0' AND filename<>''");
$stmtcounterview->execute(array());
$countview = $stmtcounterview->fetchColumn();

$getstate = isset($_GET['state']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['state']) : '';

if(!empty($getstate)){
  $query = "SELECT * FROM usa WHERE deleted='0' AND filename<>'' AND state=?";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
  $stmt->execute(array($getstate));

  $stmtcounterview = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usa WHERE deleted='0' AND filename<>'' AND state=?");
  $stmtcounterview->execute(array($getstate));
  $countview = $stmtcounterview->fetchColumn();
} else {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM usa WHERE deleted='0' AND filename<>''";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
  $stmt->execute(array());

  $stmtcounterview = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usa WHERE deleted='0' AND filename<>''");
  $stmtcounterview->execute(array());
  $countview = $stmtcounterview->fetchColumn();
}

The code is working fine, but when i pass usa.php?state=ABC, where ABC doesn't exists in my database, then it should redirect to usa.php and fetch all records.
So how can i achieve this by passing the right value to $_GET['state'] parameter.

Please read: Why check both isset() and !empty() and Should we always use prepared statements in MySQL and php or when to use these? All $query queries seem to be completely ignored.

Ah yes, and more required reading: when to use htmlspecialchars() function?

Are you asking how to conditionally clear the querystring from the url and refresh the page?  If so, that sounds like an XY Problem.  Don't reload the page, just fallback to a no-parameter query if the passed in value doesn't yield any rows in the result set.

Yes exactly @mickmackusa, I don't want to show 0 Results, just want to redirect to usa.php and show all results

How about: How to redirect to the same page in PHP

Why do you want to achieve this by passing the right value to $_GET['state'] parameter? And what is the right value?

Start by actually reading the value of the count query, and make and decision based on that

Why is this tagged with [tag:http-redirect] and [tag:query-string]? What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?
